# How to get H.264 data from an RTP stream using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtp

I know we can combine videos using `ffmpeg`, but can I use `ffmpeg` to extract the H.264 content from a decrypted *RTP* stream? If so, how?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i rtp://stream -an -vcodec copy stream.264`

Comment: the h.264 video content?

Comment: @rogerdpack Yes

Comment: @szatmary i downloaded the avi file from here http://www.engr.colostate.edu/me/facil/dynamics/avis.htm and did this ffmpeg.exe -i flame.avi -an -vcodec copy stream1.h264, i am getting error on this.

Comment: what error message?